# OpenSSL configuration error - con npm instalado con node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, openssl

Intenté instalar node.js que viene junto con npm.

Cuando ejecuto  `node --version`, recibo esto:

```
v17.3.0
```

pero cuando ejecuto `npm --version`, recibo este error:

```
OpenSSL configuration error:
20420000:error:80000002:system library:BIO_new_file:No such file or directory:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\psqlODBC\etc\openssl.cnf, rb)
20420000:error:10000080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:75:
20420000:error:07000072:configuration file routines:def_load:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:179:
OpenSSL configuration error:
FC120000:error:80000002:system library:BIO_new_file:No such file or directory:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\psqlODBC\etc\openssl.cnf, rb)
FC120000:error:10000080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:75:
FC120000:error:07000072:configuration file routines:def_load:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:179:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, si tienes Node corriendo detén el proceso.

Abre una consola de Windows o terminal e introduce el siguiente comando:

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=
```

y presiona enter.

Luego vuelve a intentar correr `npm start` o `npm --version`

Es un [bug](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40547) aparentemente más relacionado con PostgreSQL que con Node.

Comment: Me funcionó, muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, me alegro que te haya sido útil. No encontré en español una respuesta similar por eso decidí compartirlo.